# WordPress Search does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a WP theme. My search function does not work well. 
When I hit the Search button nothing happens, it doen't even refresh the page. But when I type in the URL www.example.com/?s=Lorem I get the results. I don't understand why my search button does not work. Can anyone tell me how can I fix this problem? Below you will see my search.php and searchform.php

**search.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <main role="main">
        <!-- section -->
        <section>

            <h1><?php echo sprintf( __( '%s search-form Search Results for ', 'mytheme' ), $wp_query->found_posts ); echo get_search_query(); ?></h1>

            <?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>
        </section>
        <!-- /section -->
    </main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**searchform.php**

```
<div id="search">
    <button type="button" class="close" style="background:transparent;border-radius: 0px;">x</button>
    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>">
        <input type="search" value="" name="s" placeholder="<?php if (!empty($theme_options['search_placeholder'])) { echo $theme_options['search_placeholder']; } ?>" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><?php _e( 'Search', 'mytheme' ); ?></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This code works for me with twentysixteen theme but the placeholder naturally shows empty. What happens when you var_dump($theme_options)?

Answer (score 0):

May be you miss something. Replace input tag code with following code

```
<input type="search" 
   value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" 
   name="s" 
   placeholder="<?php if(!empty($theme_options['search_placeholder'])) { 
      echo $theme_options['search_placeholder'];
   } ?>"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. 
My initial code above was working fine after I removed

```
wp_register_script('slick.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slick.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
        //wp_enqueue_script('slick.min'); // Enqueue it!
```

from my **functions.php**